# В чем отличие подзапросов EXISTS и IN?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT company_name, contact_name, customer_id
FROM customers
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT customer_id FROM orders
             WHERE orders.customer_id = customers.customer_id
             AND freight BETWEEN 50 AND 100)
```

Интересует работа EXISTS в данном случае, если возвращается что-то в подзапросе, то должно выбраться все в основном запросе или нет? В данном случае возвращается 65 строк.
Тогда почему если написать такое, то выберет сразу все записи?

```
SELECT company_name, contact_name, customer_id
FROM customers
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT customer_id FROM orders
             WHERE orders.customer_id = 'VINET')
```

получается фильтрация идет также как при обычном IN или как? Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> В чем отличие подзапросов EXISTS и IN?

1. `WHERE EXISTS` - как правило, коррелированный подзапрос. `WHERE IN` - как правило, нет.
2. `WHERE EXISTS` прерывает поиск, как только найдена первая запись, соответствующая подзапросу. `WHERE IN` всегда получает полный набор записей подзапроса, а затем проверяет на вхождение.
3. Подзапрос во `WHERE IN` допускает повторное использование, если он некоррелированный. Подзапрос во `WHERE EXISTS`, если он коррелированный, не предусматривает повторного использования по своей сути и выполняется для каждой записи.
4. `WHERE IN` может содержать статическое выражение (обычно список литералов), тогда как `WHERE EXISTS` всегда содержит подзапрос.

---

Применительно к запросу, показанному в тексте вопроса.

Запрос в условии - некоррелированный. Поэтому он будет выполнен независимо, а его результат использован в дальнейшем как константа.

Т.е. суммарно - если в таблице `orders` есть хотя бы одна запись с `orders.customer_id = 'VINET'`, то будет возвращён результат выполнения  запроса `SELECT company_name, contact_name, customer_id FROM customers`, иначе будет возвращён пустой набор записей.

---

Коррелированным называется подзапрос, если результат его выполнения зависит от значений, полученных из внешнего подзапроса. Например, от значения поля записи во внешнем запросе, для которой выполняется подзапрос.

Некоррелированным называется подзапрос, результат которого не зависит от внешних значений.

Comment: стоит добавить сноску что такое `коррелированный`/`некоррелированный` запрос

Comment: @Grundy ну надо же дать возможность автору хоть что-то сделать самостоятельно... если не найти ответ в документации, то хотя бы сказать что он этого не знает.

Comment: Ответ не только для автора вопроса :)

Comment: Поправьте если нет так понял, если в подзапросе ссылаться на внешнюю таблицу как у меня в первом случае, то будет проверка для каждого значения как если бы я написал там IN, во втором случае если в подзапросе выполняется селект, то следом выполняется основной запрос в том виде в котором написан.

Comment: @Random.random *если в подзапросе ссылаться на внешнюю таблицу как у меня в первом случае, то будет проверка для каждого значения* Да. *как если бы я написал там IN* Нет. Я ж сказал - EXISTS просто проверит, есть ли хоть какая-то запись, а WHERE IN ещё требует и вхождения значения в список. Да, WHERE IN - оно `WHERE что-то IN (что-то)`, а `WHERE EXISTS` - оно `WHERE EXISTS (что-то)`.   *во втором случае если в подзапросе выполняется селект, то следом выполняется основной запрос в том виде в котором написан* Да.

Comment: Получается при коррелированном запросе берется первое значение из внешней таблицы, проверяется на условие, если тру, то выводит, если нет, то следующее и тд?

Comment: @Random.random Всё верно. Ну разве что с мелкой поправкой - не "выводит", а "помечает, что эту запись нужно будет вывести", ибо процесс вывода отделён от процесса выборки.